# Reducir Cursor en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo una duda sobre cursores, en mi aplicación he creado un cursor que recoge datos de una base interna de la app, en este caso recoge las impresoras térmicas conectadas por red, tengo 2 zonas de impresión y a cada una de ellas he asignado una impresora, al recorrer el cursor detecta que hay 2 impresoras y por tanto me imprime 2 veces, quería saber si hay alguna forma de reducir un cursor ya que cuando hago un getCount me devuelve 2 y lo que quiero es que se pare en el primer resultado de devuelva, no que lo recorra entero, he buscado algun método que me pueda servir en el API de android pero no he encontrado nada, haber si ha alguien se le ocurre que puedo hacer, o si debo hacer algo en la consulta.

Un saludo.

Comment: Si querés una sola impresora es un tema de ajustar el query para que te devuelva la impresora que necesitas solamente.

Comment: Bienvenido al foro, recuerda leer la documentación de como formular las preguntas, por otro lado, debes editar tu pregunta y agregar el cógio que estas usando, para partir de alli con la ayuda. Saludos